# Is this possible in one fast mysql query?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have three tables and i need different data from all of them. Sadly i also need to be able to extract the latest row.

Here are my tables:

**messages**: I am just storing the content of the messages inside a table because one text could be sent to multiple users

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| message_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| content    | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**conversations:** This table just reflects a single conversation between two users.

```
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| partner_id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| conversation_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| expedition_id   | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| active          | tinyint(4)       | NO   |     | 1       |                |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**conversation_messages**: This table stores the information about the actual messages exchanged.

```
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| message_id      | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| receiver_id     | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| conversation_id | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| status          | tinyint(4)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| timestamp       | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

What i want to do now to select the latest message inside each conversation and get the content from this message aswell. (It sounds simple, but it did not find a simple solution). What i tried is the following:

```
SELECT max(c_m.message_id), m.content, c_m.`status` 
FROM expedition_conversations e_c, conversation_messages c_m 
    INNER JOIN messages m ON m.message_id = c_m.message_id 
WHERE e_c.expedition_id = 1 AND (c_m.conversation_id = e_c.conversation_id)      
GROUP BY c_m.conversation_id;
```

Sadly since `GROUP BY` internally seems to selecting the first inserted row most of the time, the `content` i select from the `messages` table is wrong, while the `message_id` selected from `conversation_messages` is correct.

Any idea how to perform this in one query? If you have any suggestions to alter the table structure, i would also appreciate those.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try this version:

```
SELECT c_m.message_id, m.content, c_m.`status` 
FROM expedition_conversations e_c join
     conversation_messages c_m 
     ON c_m.conversation_id = e_c.conversation_id INNER JOIN
     messages m
     ON m.message_id = c_m.message_id 
WHERE e_c.expedition_id = 1 AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM conversation_messages cm2
                  WHERE cm2.conversation_id = c_m.conversation_id AND
                        cm2.timestamp > c_m.timestamp
                 )
```

For performance, you want an index on `conversation_messages(conversation_id, timestamp)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, because your usage of `AUTO_INCREMENT` means, that the highest id belongs to the latest message:

```
SELECT
  messages.*,
FROM
  conversations
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT conversation_id, MAX(message_id) AS maxmsgid
    FROM conversation_messages
    GROUP BY conversation_id
  ) AS latest ON latest.conversation_id=conversations.id
  INNER JOIN messages
    ON messages.message_id=latest.maxmsgid
WHERE 
  1=1 -- whatever you want or need!
```

Since this query is bound to be quite slow, you might want to consider a few options:

- Throw hardware at it: Use enough RAM and configure MySQL to go to disk for the interims table as late as possibel
- Use denormalization and have a `ON AFTER INSERT` trigger on `messages` update a field on `conversation_messages`, that holds the latest message ID

Comment: Thank you. I will keep your two options in mind. Upvoted you instead of accepting as an answer, because i did use the solution above ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this little trick:

```
SELECT c_m.message_id, m.content, c_m.status
FROM expedition_conversations e_c
JOIN (select * from (
    select * from conversation_messages
    order by message_id desc) x
  group by conversation_id) c_m ON c_m.conversation_id = e_c.conversation_id
INNER JOIN messages m ON m.message_id = c_m.message_id 
WHERE e_c.expedition_id = 1
```

This will work on your version if mysql - 5.6.19 - and should out-perform other approaches.